# Chart.js grid lines not hiding

Tags: charts, chart.js

So I'm struggling to figure out how to hide my grid lines in Chart.js. According to the [documentation here](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/styling.html), using a `false` value for all of `display, drawOnChartArea, drawTicks` should be overkill. For some reason however, the grey lines in the background STILL are being displayed:[image]

Here is my `options.scales` object:

```
  scales: {
    xAxes: [{
      gridlines: {
        display: false,
        drawOnChartArea: false,
        drawTicks: false
      },
      ticks: {
        display: false
      }
    }],
    yAxes: [{
      gridlines: {
        display: false,
        drawOnChartArea: false,
        drawTicks: false
      },
      ticks: {
        display: false,
        fontFamily: chartsFont,
        fontColor: color
      }
    }]
  }
```

Help please! I must be missing something obvious, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just change "gridlines" to "gridLines"
"L" in caps

You can see the live example on site:
http://www.chartjs.org/samples/latest/scales/gridlines-display.html

Answer (score 2):

```
vAxis: {
            gridlines: {
                color: 'none'
            }
       },
hAxis: {
            gridlines: {
                 color: 'none'
            }
         }
```

is working for me. You can try 'transparent' too I think instead of 'none'

Comment: I tried both of them, still no dice. The result is the exact same.

Comment: Hey man, I appreciate your help. It was a stupid mistake - see Jaydp's answer above.